# Unexpected behavior for setdiff() function in R

Tags: r

As I understand it, `setdiff()` compares two vectors and gives the elements that occur in one vector but do not occur in the other. If that's so, then given these vectors...

```
thing1 <- c(1,2,3)
thing2 <- c(2,3,4)
thing3 <- c(1,2,3)
```

...here's my results.

```
setdiff(thing1,thing2)
> [1] 1

setdiff(thing2,thing3)
> [1] 4

setdiff(thing1,thing3)
> numeric(0)
```

Shouldn't the comparison of `thing1` and `thing2` produce the same result as comparing `thing2` and `thing3`? How to achieve an 'outer join' sort of result (symmetric set difference) where we can see all the elements that are missing if we unioned `thing1` and `thing2`? Prefer to know functionality in R base, but would also appreciate `data.tables` approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of `setdiff()` which gives the asymmetric difference between sets. See the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/setdiff)

Comment: `setdiff(x, y)` gives those members in `x` that are not in `y` and `setdiff(y, x)` the other way around. Maybe you are looking for `union(setdiff(x,y), setdiff(y,x))`.

Comment: You may also consider `is.element(x, y)` or `x %in% y`.

Comment: They even used an exclamation point in the documentation for `setdiff` to try to get you to notice that the difference is not symmetric: `(asymmetric!) difference`.

Comment: @m0h3n Thanks for `union(setdiff...))` and `x %in% y` ideas. Had scanned right over 'asymmetric' comment in doc @joran, thx.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`setdiff` provides asymmetric difference. In this case, it does what it says on the tin.

> Shouldn't the comparison of `thing1` and `thing2` produce the same result as comparing `thing2` and `thing3`?

Well, no. But it will produce the same results as comparing `thing3` and `thing2`. The order matters. Consider your first two examples:

The first example asks, what is in `thing1` that is not in `thing2`?

```
> setdiff(thing1, thing2)
[1] 1
```

You could try the reverse, what is in `thing2` that is not in `thing1`?

```
> setdiff(thing2, thing1)
[1] 4
```

But it looks to me like the question you're asking is:

> What elements of `thing1` and `thing2` are not shared?

Which is the same as:

> What elements are in the union of `thing1` and `thing2`, but not in the intersection of the two?

```
> setdiff(union(thing1, thing2), intersect(thing1, thing2))
[1] 1 4
```