# Text subsetting of a data frame in R

Tags: r, arrays, subset, multiple-columns

I have two vectors with given names as follows in `R`:

```
A <- data.frame(c("Nick", "Maria", "Liam", "Oliver", "Sophia", "james", "Lucas; Luc"))
B  <- data.frame(c("Liam", "Luc", "Evelyn; Eva", "James", "Harper", "Amelia"))
```

I want to compare the two vectors and create a vector `C` with the names of vector `B` that are not in the vector `A`. I want the code to ignore the capital letters, i.e. to recognise that `James` and `james` is the same and if the name appear as two names (given name and preferred name), e.g., `Lucas; Luc`, to recognise it as the same.
In the end, the result must be

```
C <- data.frame(c("Evelyn; Eva", "Harper","Amelia"))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the ugliest code i did but it works.

```
A <- str_to_title(c("Nick", "Maria", "Liam", "Oliver", "Sophia", "james", "Lucas; Luc"))
B  <- str_to_title(c("Liam", "Luc", "Evelyn; Eva", "James", "Harper", "Amelia"))

# Long version if you wish:
nested <- tibble(given=str_extract(c(A,B),"^[^;]+"),
           preferred=str_extract(c(A,B),";\\s*([^;]+)") %>% str_extract("[a-zA-Z]+"),
           list=c(rep("A",length(A)),rep("B",length(B)))) %>% nest_by(list)
A <- nested$data[[1]]
B <- nested$data[[2]]
unique_b <- B$given %in% A$given | B$given %in% A$preferred

B %>% filter(given %in% B$given[!unique_b]) %>%
  mutate(c=ifelse(is.na(preferred),given,str_c(given,preferred,sep  = "; "))
) %>% pull(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding what you mean by names appear as part of double name. However, the bulk of your question can be answered with:

- `setdiff()` to identify the differences between two sets (from tidyverse/dplyr library), and
- the base `toupper()`  to make all strings capitalized (or `tolower()` for the reverse)

We also need to name the column in the dataframe. I called both "x"

```
A <- data.frame(x=c("Nick", "Maria", "Liam", "Oliver", "Sophia", "james", "Lucas; Luc"))
B <- data.frame(x=c("Liam", "Luc", "Evelyn; Eva", "James", "Harper", "Amelia"))

library(tidyverse)
?union
union(setdiff(toupper(A$x), toupper(B$x)), setdiff(toupper(B$x), toupper(A$x)))

#[1] "NICK"        "MARIA"       "OLIVER"      "SOPHIA"      "LUCAS; LUC"  "LUC"         "EVELYN; EVA" "HARPER"      "AMELIA"
```

Note that setdiff is asymmetrical, so we need to do A different from B, combined with B different from A.

More info here [Unexpected behavior for setdiff() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548297/unexpected-behavior-for-setdiff-function-in-r)

Comment: I just edited the part about the double name. I meant the " " to contain both given and preferred name.  However, the `setdiff(toupper(B$x), toupper(A$x))`, which is more close to what am I looking for, do not work properly. I do not want `Luc` to appear in the new list since in A we have "Lucas; Luc"

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure if i got you right

```
A <- str_to_title(c("Nick", "Maria", "Liam", "Oliver", "Sophia", "james", "Lucas; Luc"))
B  <- str_to_title(c("Liam", "Luc", "Evelyn; Eva", "James", "Harper", "Amelia"))
c <- B[!A %in% B]
```

Comment: Sorry but the output `("Liam"   "Luc"    "James"  "Harper" NA)` is completely different from the desired (`"Evelyn; Eva", "Harper", "Amelia"`).

Comment: tibble(given=str_extract(c(A,B),"^[^;]+"),
           preferred=str_extract(c(A,B),";\\s*([^;]+)") %>% str_extract("[a-zA-Z]+"),
           list=c(rep("A",length(A)),rep("B",length(B)))) # try this. What exactly do you want to do with the other names?

Comment: When you write "the result must be", is it a shorthand of your desired output or you literly meant you only need these values?

Comment: "the result must be" is the desired output.

Comment: I added a working solution. I'm not sure I will be able to explain this code in a day from now :P